# CSS missing certain sections in EC2 instance but works fine in localhost. How do I resolve?

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services

I have created an EC2 instance and hosted my PHP code within this from a git clone.

On localhost my CSS shows my site as expected. When I view the same site on the IP address from my instance, the CSS does not pull through correctly. Some of it works correctly - such as colors. Other bits like max-sizing does not work. Why would this happen?

**This is the head in my HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8>
    <title>spreadsheet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

**HTML that loses its sizing**

```
<!--Hero Banner-->        
<div class='container hero' >
    <div class="hero-text" >

        <h2  class="display-4 ">You've located</h2>
        <div ><h2 class="display-4" ><strong>Gemma</strong></h2></div>
    </div>
    <img class= "container-fluid hero-image mt-2" alt = "vintage map" src="public/images/content/map.jpg">


</div>
</section>
```

**CSS of this section**

```
#container {
    position: relative;

}
.hero {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.hero-image{

    opacity: 30%;
    max-height:650px;

}
.hero-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 300px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I updated the question because the connection to the CSS file is working, but something is going wrong internally as only some bits of the CSS is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be just in your CSS alone.

For example you have your container as an ID but are calling it in your html as a class.

Also some css is missing, its possible that the `mt-2` class is overwriting your own custom classes.

My guess is when you view it locally the remote css isn't loading, or when you view it on EC2 your custom CSS isnt loading. Taking a stab in the dark here, try adding a / in front of your css calls and see if that works.

Comment: Hey Steven, I think I have to agree with you on this one that I am overwriting myself. I then lost my custom CSS on my localhost when I amended the file paths and vice versa. I'm going to strip it back and build it back with some more clarity so there are no conflicts. Thanks so much!